# How to transfer between two tz1 accounts using Taquito RPC functions such as forgeOperations and injectOperation?

Tags: rpc, operation, taquito, transfer, inject

I want to use taquito to successfully transfer the amount between two tz1 accounts without using the transfer function of contract API or wallet API.

Instead, I want to use taquito RPC functions such as forgeOperations and injectOperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below function to achieve the desired.

Note to give input like below:

```
const input = {
    "receiverAddress"   :   "address of receiver",
    "value"             :   "amount in Mutez",
    "sender"            :   "address of sender", 
    "senderPublicKey"   :   "public key of sender",   
    "senderPrivateKey"  :   "private key of sender"
}
```

Transfer Function:

```
const transfer = async function(input){
    try{
        const publicKey = await getManagerKey(input.sender);
        if(publicKey != null && typeof(publicKey) != 'string') throw publicKey;
        var counter = await getCounter(input.sender);
        if(counter.Error != undefined) throw counter;
        var contents = [];
        if(publicKey == null){
            const estimatedReveal = await estimateReveal(input);
            if(estimatedReveal.Error != undefined) throw estimatedReveal;
            if(estimatedReveal != undefined){
                contents.push({
                    "kind"          :   "reveal",
                    "fee"           :   estimatedReveal.suggestedFee,
                    "public_key"    :   input.senderPublicKey,
                    "source"        :   input.sender,
                    "gas_limit"     :   estimatedReveal.gasLimit,
                    "storage_limit" :   estimatedReveal.storageLimit,
                    "counter"       :   counter 
                });
                counter = (Number(counter) + 1 ).toString();
            }else{
                throw({
                    "Error"     :   "CREATE_TRANSACTION :: REVEAL :: Repeat Error",
                    "message"   :   "Trying to reveal already revealed account"
                });
            }
        }
        const estimatedTransaction = await estimateTransaction(input);
        if(estimatedTransaction.Error != undefined) throw estimatedTransaction;
        contents.push({
            "kind": "transaction",
            "fee": estimatedTransaction.suggestedFee,
            "gas_limit": estimatedTransaction.gasLimit,
            "storage_limit": estimatedTransaction.storageLimit,
            "amount": input.value,
            "destination": input.receiverAddress,
            "parameters" : undefined,
            "source": input.sender,
            "counter": counter
        });
        console.log(contents);
        const blockHeader = await getBlockHeader();
        const opObj = {
            "branch"    :   blockHeader.hash,
            "contents"  :   contents
        }
        const forgedBytes = await forgeOperations(opObj);
        console.log(forgedBytes);
        const signedObject = await signOp(forgedBytes, input.senderPrivateKey);
        console.log(signedObject);
        const opHash = await injectOp(signedObject.opbytes);
        console.log(opHash);
    }catch(error){
        var errObj = {};
        errObj["Error"] = "CREATE_TRANSACTION :: Error";
        errObj["message"] = "Unable to create transaction";
        if(error.Error != undefined){
            errObj["memo"] = error;
        }else{
            errObj["memo"] = error.toString();
        }
        console.log(errObj);
        return errObj;
    }
}
```

Note that I have used some RPC functions like getManagerKey, getBlockHeader, getBlock and getContract.

I also have used some estimate functions of the taquito. Find below:

```
const estimateReveal = async function(input){
    try{
        tezos.setProvider({ signer: new InMemorySigner(input.senderPrivateKey) });
        const estimated = await tezos.estimate
                    .reveal()
                    .then((est) => {
                        return({
                            "gasLimit"     :   est.gasLimit.toString(),
                            "storageLimit" :   est.storageLimit.toString(),
                            "suggestedFee" :   est.suggestedFeeMutez.toString()
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        throw({
                            "Error"     :   "TAQUITO :: Network Error",
                            "message"   :   "Taquito estimate method returned error",
                            "memo"      :   JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)
                        })
                    });
        return estimated;
    }catch(error){
        var errObj = {};
        errObj["Error"] = "CREATE_TRANSACTION :: ESTIMATE_REVEAL :: Network Error";
        errObj["message"] = "Unable to estimate reveal operation";
        if(error.Error != undefined){
            errObj["memo"] = error;
        }else{
            errObj["memo"] = error.toString();
        }
        return errObj;
    }
}
```

and

```
const estimateTransaction = async function(input){
    try{
        tezos.setProvider({ signer: new InMemorySigner(input.senderPrivateKey) });
        const estimated = await tezos.estimate
                    .transfer({ to: input.receiverAddress, amount: Number(input.value)/1000000 })
                    .then((est) => {
                        return({
                            "gasLimit"     :   est.gasLimit.toString(),
                            "storageLimit" :   est.storageLimit.toString(),
                            "suggestedFee" :   est.suggestedFeeMutez.toString()
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        throw({
                            "Error"     :   "TAQUITO :: Network Error",
                            "message"   :   "Taquito estimate method returned error",
                            "memo"      :   JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)
                        })
                    });
        return estimated;
    }catch(error){
        var errObj = {};
        errObj["Error"] = "CREATE_TRANSACTION :: ESTIMATE_TRANSACTION:: Network Error";
        errObj["message"] = "Unable to estimate transaction operation";
        if(error.Error != undefined){
            errObj["memo"] = error;
        }else{
            errObj["memo"] = error.toString();
        }
        return errObj;
    }
}
```

and

```
const getCounter = async function(address){
    try{
        const contractData = await getContract(address);
        if(contractData.Error != undefined) throw contractData;
        return (Number(contractData.counter) + 1).toString();
    }catch(error){
        return error;
    }
}
```

Please feel free to comment down below if you need any clarifications. Thanks

**NOTE:** Import necessary packaged from '@taquito/rpc', '@taquito/taquito' and '@taquito/signer'.